# How to you hide the emitting object when exporting?

Tags: particles, export

I'm trying to export a 3D model to put in Visual Studio Code. I have made a cube to hold particles in and I've unchecked 'show emitter'. I also created a separate collection to hold the black sphere the particles are based on, which I saw someone say worked for them.

[image]

However when I upload into Sketchfab the model still includes the original cube (below). Does anyone know of a way to hide the cube?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to Apply the particle modifier to turn it into an actual object.

[image]

Then you would just select that object and export it as an FBX. "Show emitter" is just an in-blender thing.

Comment: Ahhh right, thank you! :)